# How can I reset a factory_girl sequence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Provided that  I have a project factory

```
Factory.define :project do |p|
  p.sequence(:title)    { |n| "project #{n} title"                  }
  p.sequence(:subtitle) { |n| "project #{n} subtitle"               }
  p.sequence(:image)    { |n| "../images/content/projects/#{n}.jpg" }
  p.sequence(:date)     { |n| n.weeks.ago.to_date                   }
end
```

And that I'm creating instances of project

```
Factory.build :project
Factory.build :project
```

By this time, the next time I execute Factory.build(:project) I'll receive an instance of Project with a title set to "project 3 title" and so on. Not surprising.

Now say that I wish to reset my counter within this scope. Something like:

```
Factory.build :project #=> Project 3
Factory.reset :project #=> project factory counter gets reseted
Factory.build :project #=> A new instance of project 1
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I'm currently using the following versions:

factory_girl (1.3.1)
factory_girl_rails (1.0)

Comment: Hi one can tell me where did you add factories.rb file. In features file or in spec file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After tracing my way through the source code, I have finally come up with a solution for this. If you're using factory_girl 1.3.2 (which was the latest release at the time I am writing this), you can add the following code to the top of your factories.rb file:

```
class Factory  
  def self.reset_sequences
    Factory.factories.each do |name, factory|
      factory.sequences.each do |name, sequence|
        sequence.reset
      end
    end
  end
  
  def sequences
    @sequences
  end
  
  def sequence(name, &block)
    s = Sequence.new(&block)
    
    @sequences ||= {}
    @sequences[name] = s
    
    add_attribute(name) { s.next }
  end
  
  def reset_sequence(name)
    @sequences[name].reset
  end
  
  class Sequence
    def reset
      @value = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in Cucumber's env.rb, simply add:

```
After do
  Factory.reset_sequences
end
```

I'd assume if you run into the same problem in your rspec tests, you could use rspecs after :each method.

At the moment, this approach only takes into consideration sequences defined within a factory, such as:

```
Factory.define :specialty do |f|
  f.sequence(:title) { |n| "Test Specialty #{n}"}
  f.sequence(:permalink) { |n| "permalink#{n}" }
end
```

I have not yet written the code to handle: Factory.sequence...

Comment: Hi any one can tell me where can I add factories.rb file. In features file or in spec file.

Comment: See @brandon's post below for an answer with higher votes and no monkey-patching required.

Answer (score 46):

Just call FactoryGirl.reload in your before/after callback.  This is defined in the FactoryGirl codebase as:

```
module FactoryGirl
  def self.reload
    self.factories.clear
    self.sequences.clear
    self.traits.clear
    self.find_definitions
  end
end
```

Calling FactoryGirl.sequences.clear is not sufficient for some reason. Doing a full reload might have some overhead, but when I tried with/without the callback, my tests took around 30 seconds to run either way.  Therefore the overhead is not enough to impact my workflow.

Comment: Thanks it works. I added this code in my spec->support->reset.rb file and I add `After do
 FactoryGirl.reload
end` this in env.rb file

Answer (score 12):

There is a class method called `sequence_by_name` to fetch a sequence by name, and then you can call `rewind` and it'll reset to 1.

```
FactoryBot.sequence_by_name(:order).rewind
```

Or if you want to reset all.

```
FactoryBot.rewind_sequences
```

[Here is the link to the file on github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/1d6170af2bf593528a604a63981b054803aa01a8/lib/factory_bot.rb#L104-L110)

Answer (score 9):

For googling people: without further extending, just do `FactoryGirl.reload`

```
FactoryGirl.create :user
#=> User id: 1, name: "user_1"
FactoryGirl.create :user
#=> User id: 2, name: "user_2"

DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation #wiping out database with truncation
FactoryGirl.reload

FactoryGirl.create :user
#=> User id: 1, name: "user_1"
```

works for me on

```
* factory_girl (4.3.0)
* factory_girl_rails (4.3.0)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048658

Answer (score 5):

According to ThoughBot **[Here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/10983530140/getting-sequential-a-look-into-a-factory-girl)**, the need to reset the sequence between tests is an anti-pattern.

**To summerize**:

If you have something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    sequence(:name) {|n| "Category #{n}" }
  end
end
```

Your tests should look like this:

```
Scenario: Create a post under a category
   Given a category exists with a name of "My Category"
   And I am signed in as an admin
   When I go to create a new post
   And I select "My Category" from "Categories"
   And I press "Create"
   And I go to view all posts
   Then I should see a post with the category "My Category"
```

Not This:

```
Scenario: Create a post under a category
  Given a category exists
  And I am signed in as an admin
  When I go to create a new post
  And I select "Category 1" from "Categories"
  And I press "Create"
  And I go to view all posts
  Then I should see a post with the category "Category 1"
```

Comment: I find it very useful to reset sequences between tests, thus I now exactly what to expect on each and my tests are more declarative.

Comment: How can you guarantee that a category exists with a name of "Category 1" if you don't reset the sequence that gives the name of "Category 1"?

Comment: The article you link makes it much more explicit than your summary here: if the test depends on a specific value, then it should explicitly pass that value to the factory.

Answer (score 2):

Had to ensure sequences are going from 1 to 8 and restart to 1 and so on. Implemented like this:

```
class FGCustomSequence
  def initialize(max)
    @marker, @max = 1, max
  end
  def next
    @marker = (@marker >= @max ? 1 : (@marker + 1))
  end
  def peek
    @marker.to_s
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    sequence(:picture, FGCustomSequence.new(8)) { |n| "image#{n.to_s}.png" }
  end
end
```

The [doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits) says "The value just needs to support the `#next` method." But to keep you CustomSequence object going through it needs to support `#peek` method too. Lastly I don't know how long this will work because it kind of hack into FactoryGirl internals, when they make a change this may fail to work properly

Comment: This can be simplified to `sequence(:picture, 0) { |n| "image#{n % 8 + 1}.png" }`

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in way to reset a sequence, see the source code here:

http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/sequence.rb

However, some people have hacked/monkey-patched this feature in.  Here's an example:

http://www.pmamediagroup.com/2009/05/smarter-sequencing-in-factory-girl/

Comment: Hello, I've been lurking their source as well and also found that post you linked. Haven't exactly figured out how to solve my issue yet.

Factory.sequences behaves [apparently] in a weird way.

Factory.build(:project) #=> project 1
Factory.build(:project) #=> project 2
Factory.sequences.delete(:project)
Factory.build(:project) #=> project 3

Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: The sequence is giving you a guarenteed unique ID here, not the count of the objects.  That behavior is exactly what you should expect.  These are used to make sure a name is generated uniquely every time you make an instance from the factory.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to reset :)

Answer (score 0):

To reset particular sequence you can try

```
# spec/factories/schedule_positions.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :position do |n| 
    n
  end

  factory :schedule_position do
    position
    position_date Date.today
    ...
  end
end

# spec/models/schedule_position.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe SchedulePosition do
  describe "Reposition" do
    before(:each) do
      nullify_position
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:schedule_position, 10)
    end
  end

  protected

  def nullify_position
    position = FactoryGirl.sequences.find(:position)
    position.instance_variable_set :@value, FactoryGirl::Sequence::EnumeratorAdapter.new(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: In version 4.5.0, I managed to do it using `FactoryGirl.configuration.sequences[:iterator].instance_variable_get("@value").instance_variable_set("@value", 1)` (where ':iterator' is the name of the sequence).  Note that this only works on global sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cucumber you can add this to a step definition:

```
Given(/^I reload FactoryGirl/) do
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

Then just call it when needed.