# Reset 'sequence' for FactoryGirl tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Does anyone know how to reset the sequence method for FactoryGirl?

I have a factory that creates a list of tasks and I want to order to start at 1 every time. I use 'sequence' because the task list is a associated model, so I would need the order to increase every time I use `FactoryGirl.create` until I call a reset.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write `FactoryGirl.reload` in the before/after callback of the test file.

**Example code snippet**

```
  before do
    FactoryGirl.reload
    .
    .
    .
  end
```

The '.' represents other code.

Preferably write `FactoryGirl.reload unless FactoryGirl.factories.blank?` so that FactoryGirl does not reload, when it does not have to.

---

Doing a full reload of FactoryGirl might have some overhead on the time it takes to process the test(s); this is also what is described as [Anti-Patterns](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/10983530140/getting-sequential-a-look-into-a-factory-girl).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `FactoryGirl.reload` and thus creating an [Anti-Pattern](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/10983530140/getting-sequential-a-look-into-a-factory-girl) effect. You could pass unique values to FactoryGirl to increment for those fields when it creates the new entries.

**Example code snippet** (This example code creates 5 tasks assuming the Factory is called Task)

```
  before do
    (1..5).each do |n|
      FactoryGirl.create(:task,
        name:       "Task_unique_test_name#{n}"
      )
    end
  end
```

That way the new set of tasks order starts at 1 every time and you avoid having to reload FactoryGirl.

Comment: This seems to work well inside a `let` block as a way to create a collection of model objects (or children of a parent model) and consistently get the same results every time.