# Capybara::ElementNotFound on Dropdown Collection Select using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why this test isn't passing in Rspec. It works in the browser.

I have a Course form that belongs_to a Grade object. In the Course form, there is a select box that allows the user to select Grade:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @course] do |course| %>
...
<%= course.label :grade_id, "What age are the students?" %>
<%= course.collection_select(:grade_id, Grade.all, :id, :grade_level, options ={:prompt => "Select Grade"})  %>
```

My test in Rspec looks like this:

```
describe "A workign form" do
  before do
    sign_in_via_form #signs the user in
    visit new_user_course_path(@user) #references @user, defined in Helper
  end
let(:course){@user.courses}

  context "With valid information" do
    it "adds a course" do
      expect {
        fill_in 'course_name', with:'Course Name'
        select 'Fall', from: 'course_course_semester'
        select '2012', from: 'course_course_year'
        select 'Grade 5', from: 'course_grade_id'
        fill_in 'course_summary', with: 'Perfunctory Summary'
        fill_in 'course_objectives_attributes_0_objective', with: "an objective"
        click_button "submit"
     }.to change(course, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
...#other tests
end #describe block
```

The HTML generated in my form looks like this:

```
<label for="course_grade_id">What age are the students?</label>
<select id="course_grade_id" name="course[grade_id]"><option value="">Select Grade</option>
    <option value="1">Kindergarten</option>
    <option value="2">Grade 1</option>
    <option value="3">Grade 2</option>
    <option value="4">Grade 3</option>
    <option value="5">Grade 4</option>
    <option value="6">Grade 5</option>
    <option value="7">Grade 6</option>
    <option value="8">Grade 7</option>
    <option value="9">Grade 8</option>
    <option value="10">Grade 9</option>
    <option value="11">Grade 10</option>
    <option value="12">Grade 11</option>
    <option value="13">Grade 12</option>
    <option value="14">High School</option>
</select>
```

Let me know if there's other code needed; I'm more than happy to provide it. My other select boxes are working, but they're also part of the model with Arrays driving the contents. In this case, though, an associated model is driving the content. I'm not sure if that matters, there it is if it does.

Comment: Have you populated the grades before the test?

Comment: I'm not sure...the grades are in a separate table, grades, which is where the values in the collection_select is coming from. I don't have grades explicitly anywhere in my test. Should I add them somewhere? Where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data for the dropdown comes from the database. Rails uses separate DB for test, and its tables are empty by default. So you need to populate the grades table in order to have some options in the dropdown.

With FactoryGirl it can looks like

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :grade do
    sequence(:grade_level) { |n| "Grade #{n}" }
  end
end
```

And the test

```
describe "A workign form" do
  before do
    sign_in_via_form #signs the user in
    FactoryGirl.create_list(:grade, 14) # fill the grades table before visit the page
    visit new_user_course_path(@user) #references @user, defined in Helper
  end
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in this direction; I didn't realize how the databases were working in the test environment and looking through the logs while implementing this was really helpful.

Comment: One word of caution (for folks who might see this looking to solve the same problem), this method keeps incrementing the sequence indefinitely through each of your examples. To reset the sequence for each test, I used after(:each) block with FactoryGirl.reload. According to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359168/how-can-i-reset-a-factory-girl-sequence that's an "anti-pattern", but it worked for me for now.

Comment: +1 for jflores recommendation to use 'FactoryGirl.reload'. On a side note, one tool that helped me troubleshoot this timing issue was the 'launchy' gem. You can toss 'save_and_open_page' in at the various parts of your test execution and see when/if the view's collection_select has been populated.

Comment: To add to @jflores and @wintondeshong... you can instead use `FactoryGirl.reload unless FactoryGirl.factories.blank?` to avoid FactoryGirl from reloading when it does not have to. You can even try avoiding the use of `FactoryGirl.reload` due to the [Anti-Pattern](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/10983530140/getting-sequential-a-look-into-a-factory-girl) effect, by following the question I asked... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049443/.