# How can I avoid using 'FactoryGirl.reload' due to using 'sequence' in my factories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Having to use `FactoryGirl.reload` likely to put some overhead on the time it takes to run all tests (when many tests exist) and also it is described as an [Anti-Pattern](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/10983530140/getting-sequential-a-look-into-a-factory-girl).

How can I keep using the sequencing for unique fields, yet test for the correct values?

You can see in my code that...

- I have to call `FactoryGirl.reload` so that the increment starts at `1` in case any previous tests have already been run.
- I have to state `:count => 1` because there will only ever be one instance of that value.

**spec/factories/clients.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    name                "Name"
    sequence(:email}    { |n| "email#{n}@example.com" }
    sequence(:username) { |n| "username#{n}" }
  end
end
```

**spec/clients/index.html.erb_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "clients/index" do
  before do
    FactoryGirl.reload
    (1..5).each do
      FactoryGirl.create(:client)
    end
    @clients = Client.all
  end

  it "renders a list of clients" do
    render
    # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat matchers
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Name".to_s, :count => 5
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "email1@example.com".to_s, :count => 1
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "username1".to_s, :count => 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing in special names for this particular test?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "clients/index" do
  before do
    (1..5).each do |num|
      FactoryGirl.create(:client, username: "special#{num}")
    end
    @clients = Client.all
  end

  it "renders a list of clients" do
    render
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "special1".to_s, :count => 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Great, thank you - that worked! I knew I needed to pass through special field values, but could not quite figure how to increment them... makes sense now.

Comment: No problem, by the way why are you calling `to_s` on a string?

Comment: I left them in from what RSpec generated. Do you think taking them out would speed up the tests, seeing they are already strings?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to mind.blank's answer... If you then wish to test the incremented values, place them inside an incremental loop as well.

```
  it "renders a list of clients" do
    render
    (1..5).each do |num|
      assert_select "tr>td", :text => "special#{num}".to_s, :count => 1
    end
  end
```