# Proper way of resetting sequence in FactoryGirl before every tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am using FactoryGirl and populate unique attribute whenever the model is made. The problem with my model `form` is that there are only 4 different types available for `form_type` attribute. So I need to reset the `sequence` everytime I run tests. Like below, I user `before do` block to call `FactoryGirl.reload`. However, I saw an article saying it is anti-pattern to FactoryGirl. What is the best way to reset the sequence in FactoryGirl instead of calling `FactoryGirl.reload` before every test?

Here is my `forms.rb` Factorygirl file,

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :form do
    association :user
        sequence :form_type do |n|
            Form.form_types.values[n]
        end

  end
end
```

Here is my form.rb model file:

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, required: true

    enum form_types: { :a => "Form A", :b => "Form B", :c => "Form C", :d => "Form D"}

  validates :form_type, presence: true
  validates :form_type, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}

end
```

Here is my forms_controller_spec.rb file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe FormsController, type: :controller do

  login_user

    let(:form) {
        FactoryGirl.create(:form, user: @current_user)
    }

    let(:forms) {
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:form , 3, user: @current_user)

    }

    let(:form_attributes) {
        FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:form, user: @current_user)
    }

    describe "GET #index" do
        before do
            FactoryGirl.reload
        end

        it "loads all of the forms into @forms" do
            get :index
            expect(assigns(:forms)).to match_array(@forms)
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it seems like the purpose of FG sequences is to ensure unique numbers. Or at least that's what I've used it for. You may be able to hack into FG if this is what you really want.

This question may help.

[How can I reset a factory_girl sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359168/how-can-i-reset-a-factory-girl-sequence)